# Count `Pat`s in a Module

Tags: haskell, uniplate

I need to count the number of [`Pat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Pat) in a haskell [`Module`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Module). I know the simplest way is to pattern match on each level of the AST, which will result in a huge function that looks like the entire AST. I believe there's some way to take advantage of typeclasses like `Functor` or the `State Monad` to lean on some existing function that walks the tree (like `prettyPrint`) and trace a counter along, but I'm not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: Suppose you get to a `PInfixApp pat1 qname pat2`... do you want to recurse into `pat1` and `pat2` or just stop?

Comment: They have [`Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data) instances, so you could use generics.

Comment: @user5402 I want to recurse

Comment: @luqui can you elaborate?

Comment: @rem, it will take a bit of learning.  The [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/) (the 2003 one, at the bottom) is pretty good and easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very easy using [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate):

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.Exts

findPats :: Data a => a -> [Pat]
findPats = universeBi

test = do
  content <- readFile "Simple.hs"
  case parseModule content of
    ParseFailed _ e -> error e
    ParseOk a       -> do
      forM_ (findPats a) $ \p -> do
        putStrLn $ "got a pat: " ++ show p
```

Essentially it's just the `universeBi` function.

Comment: Awesome, I underestimated uniplate, I'll have to give it another look